# How Using #variable (NgForm input Directives) in Model-driven-form?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to use #variable="ngForm" in angular2. How can I use it on the formControl input ? There are so many changes in each version of Angular and I can't use #variable instead of using "feedbackForm.controls.personalData.controls.firstName" which is so long to tape. Don't know if there is onother way to do this. Thank you.

```
 <form [formGroup]="feedbackForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(this.feedbackForm)">
        <div formGroupName="personalData">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                <input formControlName="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                <div class="alert-info alert-danger" 
                     *ngIf="feedbackForm.controls.personalData.controls.firstName.touched && feedbackForm.controls.personalData.controls.firstName.errors">FirstName is required</div>

        </div>
...
...
...
```

**********constructor**********

```
 constructor(@Inject(FormBuilder) fb: FormBuilder) {


 this.feedbackGroup = fb.group({
        comment: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.feedbackForm = fb.group({
        personalData: fb.group({
            firstName: [``, Validators.required],
            lastName: [``, Validators.compose([Validators.required, CustomerValidators.cannotContainSpace]), CustomerValidators.shouldBeUnique],
            phoneNumber: []
        }),
        feedback: this.feedbackGroup
    });
}
```

Comment: you can also do it with `personalData.get('firstName').touched`

Comment: check https://toddmotto.com/angular-2-forms-template-driven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you should **not** mix and match the model and template driven form.
What I'd suggest:

```
<form [formGroup]="feedbackForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(this.feedbackForm)">
        <div [formGroup]="personalData">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="firstName">First name</label>
                <input [formControl]="firstName" id="firstName" type="text" class="form-control" required />
                <div class="alert-info alert-danger" 
                     *ngIf="firstName.touched && firstName.errors">FirstName is required</div>

        </div>
```

Inside the class

```
export class thatComponent {
    private firstName:FormControl;
    private personalData:FormGroup;
    private feedbackForm:FormGroup;
    constructor(){
        this.feedbackForm = .... // what ever you've done 

        this.personalData = this.feedbackForm.get(['personalData'])
        this.firstName = this.personalData.get(['firstName'])

     }

}
```

Comment: how can I do the modifications in the updated constructor (in the top post) ?

Comment: correct answer :
this.feedbackForm.get("personalData.firstName") to access to an attribute into PersonalData